# Manage multiple KieContainers

Tags: jboss, drools, kie

I've around ~50k user specific drool files, using which we return the computations to a REST API request.

What are the possible ways to manage such number of different KieContainers so that I don't have to initialise them in every API call?

Currently I was using Guava Cache to cache KieContainer but the limitation with this approach is that it creates an in-memory cache on each pod. However, as the service is running on k8 pods, kie container cached by 1 of the pods is not available to others.

Comment: sounds the perfect case for Knative with autoscaling, look for this video which gives some idea how to architect and develop a Drools based Knative application https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGXJ_bEyTmo the demo uses drools-dmn but it would be analogous with drools-drl

Comment: Why are you initializing the containers every API call?:

Comment: Every api call will have a different entity having it's own set of custom rules. Would it be a good practice to keep 50K containers in the memory? @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: Why not? I kept 700,000 in memory once upon a time. It depends on the performance characteristics of your application and your SLAs. A compromise might be to load them into memory on the first call, reuse them for subsequent calls, and then after some period of inactivity, unload them (eg like a cache.)